# iOS - Why enabling autolayout make re-sizing and re-positioning views with code won't work?

Tags: ios, layout, autolayout, xib

I have an xib which its content is like this:

[image]

The orange view is ***view_b*** which is an `UIView` containing a `UITextField`, while the `UITableView` is ***tblv_a***. And ***view_content*** is UIView that containing the two views.

What I want to accomplish is to resize the ***view_content***'s and its subviews' sizes whenever the keyboard is showing, i.e. while the user is editing in the `UITextField`. And I tried to do this with the following codes in `keyboardDidShow:`:

```
NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
CGRect kbRect = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

CGRect convertContentRect = [self.view convertRect:CGRectFromString(str_contentViewRect) toView:self.view];
CGRect coverRect = CGRectIntersection(kbRect, convertContentRect);

self.view_content.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectFromString(str_contentViewRect).origin.x, CGRectFromString(str_contentViewRect).origin.y, CGRectFromString(str_contentViewRect).size.width, CGRectFromString(str_contentViewRect).size.height - coverRect.size.height);

self.tblv_a.height = self.view_content.height - self.view_b.height;
self.view_b.y = self.tblv_a.y_height;
```

However, when I try the result with simulator, it didn't work as expected, instead, it gives the following result:

[image]

After trying to figure out what's wrong, I tried to disable autolayout in interface builder, then it works as expected, which is:

[image]

I didn't set any constraints on the views, and I checked about the frames of the views and they seem correct. So I guess autolayout is the source of the problem, but I have no idea why this is happening, can anyone help?

And if I want to enable autolayout to deal with different screen sizes, how should I solve this?

Thanks!

(***view_content***'s background color is light gray, while ***tblv_a*** is clear color)

Answer (score 0):

If auto layout is on, then the system will add default constraints if you don't add your own. When constraints are in place, you shouldn't set any frames. If you need to move or resize a view, you need to do it by changing the constraints.